# Probability Guessing a Code in 3 Attempts - Clarification

Tags: probability

For simplicity, say you have a 2 digit code where you can select numbers 1, 2, and 3 for each of the 2 entries.

What is the probability of guessing the correct code in 3 tries?  Firstly, you could simply think to yourself that there are 3x3 = 9 permutations and guessing the correct code once would be 1/9. If you get 3 attempts your chance of success is 3/9 = 1/3.

Alternatively you could use the complement approach where we say (1 - (8/9)*(7/8)*(6/9) = 1/3.

My confusion arises when we consider this complement approach and try to compare it to the former approach where probability is additive. (8/9)*(7/8)*(6/9) = the probability of guessing incorrectly in 3 attempts. We multiply the consecutive probability for each trial after updating the  trial each time. Subtracting from 1 gives us the complement, and in this case, the probability of a correct guess i.e. 1/3.

Why does it not work in reverse?  If your initial probability on the first trial is 1/9, then in the second trial it seems like it should be 1/8, and then finally 1/7, but these all lead to nonsense answers.  Why does adding up 1/9 + 1/9 + 1/9 make sense in terms of getting the guess correct, but in terms of the probability of getting the guess incorrect we can multiply the probability of consecutive trials and take the complement?

Comment: I think you meant that there are $9$ different codes, not $9$ permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work this out with four numbers rather than three to avoid the coincidence that the number of guesses is the same as the number of choices.

Suppose you have three guesses to fill the two slots with the numbers $1,2,3,4$. There are $4 \times 4 = 16$ codes and you get to try $3$ of them so the probability that you succeed is $3/16$.

That is indeed $1/16 + 1/16 + 1/16$, but that is not an the best way to think about the solution. Adding those probabilities is what you get if you just guess three times, each guess independent of the others. In that scenario you might guess the same code (correctly or incorrectly) more than once, but those coincidences exactly cancel to make the answer the sum. This fact is called the "linearity of expectation" and it's subtle.

You multiply the failure probabilities $15/16 \times 14/15 \times 13/14 = 13/16$ using the usual rule for conditional probability. Failure on the first try  reduces the number of possible choices  for the second. So that product is the probability that you fail every time. Subtract from $1$ to find the probability of at least one success.

---

**Edit**   in response to a comment from the OP asking for an example illustrating the linearity of expectation.

Consider throwing a fair die. The expected value is the average of the faces:
$$
\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6} = \frac{7}{2}.
$$
If you throw two dice the total can be anything from $2$ to $12$. When you compute the average total by looking at all $36$ possible outcomes the answer is the sum of the average values for the first and second rolls:
$$
\frac{1 \times 2 + 2 \times 3 + \cdots + 2\times 11 + 1 \times 12}{36} = 7 = \frac{7}{2} + \frac{7}{2}.
$$

Comment: This makes sense, but also, doesn't independent events imply "and" and therefore you'd multiply the probabilities and not add them? You have just pointed out, however, that one adds 1/16 + 1/16 +1/16 to get the probability of having guessed 3 times where each guess is independent.  Is this part of the subtlety you mention or something different?

Comment: The addition is the linearity of expectation, not of probability. The expected value of one choice of two numbers is $1/16$ th of a success. So the expected value of three choices is $3/16$ ths of a success. That's like saying the expected value of the sum of three dice rolls is three times the expected sum of one roll, so $3 \times (1+2+3+4+5+6)/6$. You can compute that without having to enumerate all $6^3$ ways the dice might fall. It's subtle.

Comment: "You multiply the failure probabilities $15/16×14/15×13/14=13/16$ because the three failure events are independent". I don't think independence is the reason here. Isn't it more due to conditional probability? That is, denote by $F_i$ the event that one falls in the $i$th attempt. Then $P(F_1\cap F_2 \cap F_3) = P(F_1) P(F_2|F_1) P(F_3|F_2 \cap F_1)$?

Comment: could you actually provide an example of the part where you describe the linearity of expectation wherein "the coincidences exactly cancel to make the answer the sum"?

Comment: @AndreasLenz Fixed thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would justify your first approach is that we can think of guessing codes as taking a random permutation of the $9$ different codes, and then entering in the first $3$ codes in our permutation. If the correct code is contained in the first $3$ elements of the permutation, then we will correctly crack the code. There is a $\frac{1}{9}$ probability the correct code is the first element. There is a $\frac{1}{9}$ probability the correct code is the second element.  There is a $\frac{1}{9}$ probability the correct code is the third element. Hence, in total there is a $\frac{1}{3}$ probability that the correct code is one of the first $3$ elements.

As for your third approach (the faulty one), if you are computing the probability that way, you must also account for the fact that to try to enter the code in the $i+1$st try, we must have not entered in the correct code in the first $i$ attempts. Hence, the probability that we enter the correct code on our first try is $\frac{1}{9}$. The probability that we enter the correct code on our second try is $\frac{8}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{9}$. The probability that we enter the correct code on our second try is $\frac{8}{9}\cdot\frac{7}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{7}=\frac{1}{9}$. The total probability is then $\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$